# Filling an array using stack functions

Tags: arrays, arraylist, stack, stack-overflow

I do have an array with size of 500. I want to fill the array using stack functions. how can i do it??
ps: I know that i can create something like this “stackmyarray”, and use the push functions for it. However, this is not what I want. I have a separate array called myarray[500] and I want to fill it. how can I apply stack functions to this separate array to fill it.

Comment: Is there a language you're working in?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes Hi, As you know, the Stack is a class used to contain different materials. So to use it, we need to define an object from the same class. This object easily can perform the Stack functions to fill itself. However, I do have an array that it is not an object of the Stack. A completely separate array with a size. I want to apply the stack functions to this array, to fill it. The language I am working is C++.